# How to set the background color of a pygtk window

Tags: widget, pygtk, drawingarea

I am trying to set the background color for a pyGtk window which has a single DrawingArea widget.
With this code I always get a random color everytime I launch the script:

```
widget = gtk.DrawingArea()
widget.show()
window = gtk.Window()
window.add(widget)
col = gtk.gdk.Color('#010')
window.present()
widget.window.set_background(col)
window.connect('delete-event', gtk.main_quit)
gtk.main()
```

I also tried using `widget.modify_bg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL, col)` instead of the `set_background` line, and I always get a black background.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, it seems like I was struggling too much with other things, and I didn't realize that I set the test color to #010, which is, obviously, almost black.
Using `modify_bg` works, just remember to set a reasonable color ;)

This is the working code:

```
widget = gtk.DrawingArea()
widget.show()
window = gtk.Window()
window.add(widget)
col = gtk.gdk.Color('#0f0')
window.present()
widget.modify_bg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL, col)
window.connect('delete-event', gtk.main_quit)
gtk.main()
```

By the way, does anybody know why `widget.window.set_background()` sets a random color?

Comment: Using  "import gi.repository"  I had to use gtk.StateType.NORMAL instead of gtk.STATE_NORMAL

Comment: `modify_bg` as well as `override_background_color` are now deprecated, if I understood that correctly.